# How to separate controller to outside project in Case of MVC Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an requirement where i need to separate controller outside the MVC project. My situation is like i am having 3 areas inside the MVC project and i have take out all controller inside each area into separate project by keeping all the view inside the area. I have no idea how to achieve this. If any one came across this or implemented please share your tots and codes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all after some search i found the answer and it was quite simple too.
If you have more area in you application and you want to take out the controller only to different project. As Jerode said Dll reference will do but when areas are there same controller name can come in different areas, So we need some more tweak that in area registration part we need to specify the namespace of the project

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "AreaName_default",
            "Areaname/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "controller", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new[] { "NameSpaceOfControllerAreaWhichSeparated"}
        );

    }
```

Like inside each area u need to add the namespace of corresponding separated project

Answer (score 0):

You can create two projects in the same solution.

- The first project would be your MVC4 project where views, scripts, css and areas would reside. (MyProject.PresentationLayer)
- The second project would be a class library in the solution which can contain your code such as the controllers and models. (MyProject.LogicLayer)

Using Visual Studio, *MyProject.PresentationLayer* will need a reference added to *MyProject.LogicLayer*. This can be done by right clicking References in the solution explorer and clicking the checkbox on the Solution/Projects next to *MyProject.LogicLayer*.

You should now be able to write code in *MyProject.LogicLayer* and reference the code in *MyProject.PresentationLayer* normally.

Comment: yes that's the basic but in my case i have three different Area so it may have same controller name in different area .So if i separate it into 3 MyProject.LogicLayer how the routing will work.

Comment: Okay, thanks for providing some more context on this and following up with your routing answer.